# ORA-12541: TNS:no listener

Tags: mysql, oracle

Here is the situation:

I have a computer(let's call it **server PC**, whose IP is `192.168.1.100`) that has ORACLE installed on it. I can access the data in oracle using Python on this **server PC**(This means the listener is running on **server PC**). Here is the **listener.ora** in this **server PC**:

```
# listener.ora Network Configuration File: C:\app\413022472\product\12.2.0\dbhome_1\network\admin\listener.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

SID_LIST_LISTENER =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
      #(SID_NAME = CLRExtProc)
      (SID_NAME = orcl)
      (ORACLE_HOME = C:\app\413022472\product\12.2.0\dbhome_1)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
      (ENVS = "EXTPROC_DLLS=ONLY:C:\app\413022472\product\12.2.0\dbhome_1\bin\oraclr12.dll")
    )
  )

LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 192.168.1.100)(PORT = 1521))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
    )
  )


#(HOST = DESKTOP-2RE9AJU)
```

And tnsnames.ora on **server PC**:

```
# tnsnames.ora Network Configuration File: C:\app\413022472\product\12.2.0\dbhome_1\network\admin\tnsnames.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

LISTENER_ORCL =
  (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 192.168.1.100)(PORT = 1521))

#(HOST = DESKTOP-2RE9AJU)

ORACLR_CONNECTION_DATA =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      #(SID = CLRExtProc)
      (SID = ORCL)
      (PRESENTATION = RO)
    )
  )

ORCL =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 192.168.1.100)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = orcl)
    )
  )

#(HOST = DESKTOP-2RE9AJU)
```

Now I want to use another computer(let's call it **client PC**) to connect the database on the server PC. The `Oracle` is not installed on the **client PC** but `PL/SQL Developer` and `instantclient` is installed. I open the PL/SQL, add the paths of `instantclient` and `oci.dll` in `tools`-`preference`. Then add the `username/key@//192.168.1.100:1521/orcl` in `history log`-`fixed user`. Then add a `tnsnames.ora` file in the `instantclient` folder, which is like this:

```
# tnsnames.ora Network Configuration File: C:\app\413022472\product\12.2.0\dbhome_1\network\admin\tnsnames.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

LISTENER_ORCL =
  (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 192.168.1.100)(PORT = 1521))


ORACLR_CONNECTION_DATA =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      #(SID = CLRExtProc)
      (SID = ORCL)
      (PRESENTATION = RO)
    )
  )

ORCL =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 192.168.1.100)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = orcl)
    )
  )
```

Firewalls in both of the PC are closed. They can ping each other successfully. I also tried this in `cmd` on **client PC**:`telnet 192.168.1.100 1521`, which is also successfully connected.

But it just fail when I try connect the database of **server PC** using **client PC** with PL/SQL Developer. It gives me:`ORA-12541: TNS:no listener`. Could somebody give me some suggestions? Thank you for your attention.